# <script>alert(1)</script> Showing up as first option in drop-down

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a drop-down list where everything is working correctly, with the exception that for the first option, I see alert(1).  I'm not sure where it's coming from.

The following is the Vue code generating the list:

```
  <select 
          class="form-control" 
          :class="hasError('brand') ? 'is-invalid' : ''" v-model="formData.brand">
              <option
                v-for="brand in formData.brands"
                :key="brand.brandId"
                :value="brand.brandId"
              >
                {{ brand.brandName }}
              </option>
        </select>
```

The following is how the drop-down renders:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like it is coming from your brandName. Inspect your variable brands and see what is in it.

Comment: @epascarello - lol... somehow that's in our database.  guess we'll look there!